# Terraform AWS Palo-Alto Panorama SSH "Server refused our key"

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, ssh, terraform

I've got a problem deploying a Palo-Alto Panorama (BYOL) on AWS via terraform. The problem is, after deployment I can't SSH into my machine on port 22. (Port 443 and Port 22 are open in my SG, port 443 works fine). I've checked my terraform code and just changed the AMI from Palo-Alto Panorama to a AWS Linux AMI -> everything works fine. I can SSH into the machine without any problems.

So the Palo-Alto Panorama is a problem here. I've deployed the Panorama instance in a public subnet of my VPC with an internet gateway attached (as I said, for testing purposes I just changed the AMI to AWS Linux and SSH worked!). As a username for Palo-Alto I used "admin" and set the permissions of my private key file. The error I get from SSH is:

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

Does anyone have experience with Palo-Alto Panorama on AWS? What could be going wrong here? I am trying to use: ami-0133ca0a1fd9d1051 in a public subnet in eu-central-1a with an Elastic IP attached. HTTPs works fine.

Second question: There is no way I can login in HTTPs before I configured a user via the Panorama CLI I guess, is there another way to connect via HTTPs (admin/admin does not work) before configuring a user in the CLI?

Comment: Does the AMI even allow for SSH access? I think this is a question for the AMI maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have instance metadata V2 enabled in Terraform. Remove the `metadata {}` block if you have in `aws_instance` resource.
I ran into the same issue and I got it fixed after removing the following block:

```
 metadata_options {
    http_tokens   = "required"
    http_endpoint = "enabled"
  }
```